# Getting login credentials when using webapp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, authentication, credentials

What is an accepted way to get authentication credentials (login and password) when using webapp?

I'm pretty sure that they get submitted and/or interpreted differently than the rest of the information coming through the request and I'm afraid I can't remember where exactly I'm supposed to get them from.

FYI: The requests are forced to https

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the built in authentication, or trying to roll your own? If the former, you can't access a user's credentials - just get the information you need from the User object. If the latter, you can handle the credentials any way you wish - you're rolling your own, and App Engine has no magic way to detect that what you're handling is a username or password.

Comment: Cool.  I'm rolling my own.  Thanks Nick.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got HTTPS enabled, sending them along with the request (usually a POST) is acceptable, and the "standard" method of logging in.

If you want to get clever, you could hash the password using SHA1 on the client end so that even an sslstrip won't reveal the password in plaintext (though it won't prevent replay attacks).

Comment: Hashing the password on the client is pointless - it just means that the hashed password is, to all intents and purposes, the password.

Comment: That's why I said it won't prevent replay attacks. The unfortunate truth is that people reuse passwords. They shouldn't, but they do. Whilst I'm most definitely not an advocate of promoting such behaviour, it can't hurt to take steps to protect those users. A challenge-response style hash would work well - send a token with the login page and store it in the session variables, then perform sha1($salt + $password). This makes replay impossible and makes cracking the password difficult too (as long as the salt is long).

Comment: I think people re-use passwords because its more work on average to keep track of a different password for every web service they use than to deal with the risk of an account getting hacked.

Comment: That's why I support initiatives like OpenID. If you've got a single login, it's at least a single point that can be secured properly. As long as their password is relatively strong they should be fine. And there's no excuses, since they only have to remember one password!